# Top menu with left, mid and right div

Tags: css

**Why doesn't this code set the two `<input>` elements' width as 20% of their parent, i.e. 20% of `#right`, which itself should only be the right part of the menu (and not full browser width) ?**

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#menu { background-color: yellow; }
#left {background-color: green; float: left; width: 200px; }
#mid { background-color: red; float: left; width: 40%; }
#right {background-color: blue; width: calc(100%-40%-200px);}
#a1, #a2 { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
     <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
     <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
     <div id="right">
         <input id="a1" />
         <input id="a2" />
     </div>
</div>
<div>
content of the site
</div>
```

*Note: It seems that #right uses full browser width, whereas it should have a width of 100% - 40% - 200px. Then 20% of this would be 12%-40px, i.e. I could set `#a1, #a2 { width: calc(12%-40px); }`. But this would be a dirty hack. I would really like to set #a1 and #a2's width in terms of its parent width.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked in the inspector at your running code, and noticed this:

[image]

You need to use spaces between each `calc` function value.

```
calc(100% - 40% - 200px)
```

**Update**

The reason you're seeing wrapping occur is that you need to float `#right` to the left.

```
#right {
  ...
  float: left;
}
```

Adding that one rule gives us what you're expecting.

[image]

If you notice a little gap between your text inputs (not pictured), remove the white space in your HTML where the inputs are located.

Make this:

```
<input id="a1" />
<input id="a2" />
```

into this:

```
<input id="a1" /><input id="a2" />
```

---

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#menu { background-color: yellow; }
#left {background-color: green; float: left; width: 200px; }
#mid { background-color: red; float: left; width: 40%; }
#right { background-color: blue; width: calc(100% - 40% - 200px); float: left; }
#a1, #a2 { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
     <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
     <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
     <div id="right">
         <input id="a1" /><input id="a2" />
     </div>
</div>
<div>
content of the site
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but even with this, the #right doesn't stay on top right position, just after #mid. Why?  As #left and #mid have `float: left`, #right should appear on the same line...